# Remove error validation message when user clicks/moves out of the textbox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on a reactive form in angular. Facing this problem where a field that is not required should have some validations when it is dirty or touched but as soon as the user is out of this textbox/field, the validation message should just go away. I have tried using ng-invalid but it is not working as the field when loaded for the first time is having ng-invalid class. The following is the code -

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Street Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="streetName">
   <span class="text-danger"
      *ngIf="registerForm.get('streetName').touched || registerFormControl.get('streetName').dirty" class="Required">
   <span  *ngIf="registerForm.get('streetName').error?.pattern || registerForm.get('streetName').error?.minLength">
   Pattern & Minlength error
   </span>
   <span class="text-danger"
      *ngIf="registerForm.get('streetName').error?.monthError || registerForm.get('streetName').error?.otherError">
   Month and Other Error
   </span>
   </span>   
</div>
```

FormGroup Validation -

```
streetName:['',{
   Validators: [
   Validators.pattern(0-9),
   Validators.minLength(9),
   this.customValidations.streetValid
   ],
   updateOn: 'blur'
}]
```

How do I get this validation dissappear?

Comment: When you have `updateOn: ''blur`, your validation messages itself would be appearing on blur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the focus and blur events to track if and when a user is in an input field or not.

```
<input (focus)="onFocus()" (blur)="onBlur()">
```

In this code example `onFocus()` is called when the user clicks/is-in the input box. `onBlur()` is called when the user clicks out of the input box.

We can use this to better distinguish if we should display the error message or not.

Let's say you have two inputs: Street Name and Street Address. We will create an `onFocus()` function that handles which item is focused and an `onBlur()` function that will clear the focused selection.

```
// Class variables
public selectedField = "";

function onFocus(identifier : string) {
     selectedField = identifier; // set the field
}

function onBlur() {
     selectedField = ""; // clear the field
}
```

Now, on our inputs:

```
<input  (focus)="onFocus('streetName')" (blur)="onBlur()" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="streetName">
<input (focus)="onFocus('streetAddress')" (blur)="onBlur()" type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="streetAddress">
```

Finally, we can handle if we should display the error message or not. All we need to do is add one more condition to the *ngIf of the error span.

```
<!--Example Street Name Error Span -->
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="selectedField == 'streetName' && . . . ">
     Invalid Street Name
</span

<!--Example Street Address Error Span -->
<span class="text-danger" *ngIf="selectedField == 'streetAddress' && . . . ">
     Invalid Street Address
</span
```

If you'd like a better understanding on how focus works, you can find it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp).